# How to configure access to my aws s3 bucket from aws ec2 instance via VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have installed nginx with kaltura-nginx-vod module on EC2. I would like to set up private remote read-only mode to my s3 bucket via http. Example of the desired nginx configuration:

```
vod_upstream_location /s3;

location /s3/ {
  internal;
  proxy_pass http://my-s3-bucket.s3-eu-east-1.amazonaws.com/;
}
```

I tried to create Access Point to my s3. In the settings I had pointed Access option to my VPC, but cURL returned 403 from EC2 when I tried to get some object from s3 by http url.
Also I had created IAM role with read-only S3 access and assign to my EC2, but result was same - 403.

How to set up private http-access from EC2 to s3 bucket via virtual private amazon network in same region?

Answer (score 1):

This does not work because you can't  access objects based on their URL, unless they are public. Since you've assigned IAM role to the EC2 instance you have to make [signed http request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html) to the object using the object's url with EC2 instance role credentials.

So either have to construct the valid signature yourself, or simply use **AWS SDK**, such as `boto3` for python, to do this for you. By looking at the `kaltura-nginx-vod` description it does not seem to be making any signed requests to S3 on your behalf.

Comment: Eventually I installed s3fs and mount my bucket into local file system